# Using string replace/regex in typoscript

Tags: typoscript

I am using powermail form in my typo3 project(Typo3 v 4.5).I am assigining the data from the fields of a form to database fields via typoscript.

```
tt_address.last_name.data = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|powermail_88|uid18
```

Now, the problem I am facing is that if a field contains the character '&', it is changed to to html entity representation and this is saved in database. Is there anyway I can remove this error via string replace/regex in the right side of the above expression. I tried doing it with javascript but can,t fix the problem. Please bear with me because I have very rudimentary knowledge of typoscript.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying the Ampersand is changed to Ampersand? What would be the expected behavior on your part? And unfortunately you did not state which TYPO3 version you are using, so this answer is kind of generic regarding replace and might not work for you. Eighter way:

Starting with TYPO3 4.6 the replacement function was introduced:
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Replacement/Index.html

That function is included in stdWrap too. This means you can use syntax like that:

```
tt_address.last_name.stdWrap.replacement {
  10 {
    search = &
    replace.char = 38
  }
}
```

For more examples take a look at the above link.

Comment: I have updated the question to add the missing info.Actually I wanted to say that & is represented in html entity form, I wrote it as such but it was changed to simply &

Comment: Any suggested solution for typo3 v4.5?